# How to convert C# classes to javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I have the following windows form that i am trying to change to javascript.
C# code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        public Form1()
        {
            numbers.Add(1);
            numbers.Add(1);
            numbers.Add(1);
            numbers.Add(3);
            numbers.Add(5);
            numbers.Add(9);
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = string.Join(",", numbers);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int x = numbers[numbers.Count - 1];
            int y = numbers[numbers.Count - 2];
            int z = numbers[numbers.Count - 3];

            int result = x + y + z;

            numbers.Add(result);
            label1.Text = string.Join(",", numbers);

        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var numbersThatDivideByThree = numbers.Where(n => n % 3 == 0);

            label2.Text = string.Join(",", numbersThatDivideByThree);
        }
    }
```

I am not sure how to go about doing this ,what i have so far

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var array = [1, 1, 1, 3, 9];
    console.log(array);
    document.getElementById('array').innerHTML = array;

    var numbers;
    function add() {

   //button 1
    }
  function button2()
  {

  }
});
```

im not sure how to convert button1_click and button2_click into javascript

Comment: Well, have you tried "converting" them? Doesn't seem too hard to pull off

Comment: Add button with html and operate on click events with JQuery/JS. Also give those buttons unique ids. It is simple to do.

Comment: Do not try to "convert" code manually. You either a) use an automated tool or b) understand the "source" code and write it from scratch in your "target" language. Anything in between leaves you with bad practices in your result.

Comment: where´s the problem on `<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" />`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var myArray = [1, 1, 1, 3, 9];
(function start(){
document.getElementById("myArray").innerHTML = "myArray = "+ myArray.join();

})();

function button1Click()
{
    var x = myArray[myArray.length - 1];
    var y = myArray[myArray.length - 2];
    var z = myArray[myArray.length - 3];


    var result = x + y + z;

    myArray.push(result);
    document.getElementById("myArray").innerHTML = "myArray = "+ myArray.join();
}

function button2Click()
{
   var numbersThatDivideByThree = [];
   myArray.forEach(n => 
   {
      if(n % 3 == 0){
        numbersThatDivideByThree.push(n);
      }
   }
   );
   document.getElementById("numbersBy3").innerHTML ="numbers divde by 3 = " + numbersThatDivideByThree.join();
}
```

```html
<label id="myArray"> </label>

<label id="numbersBy3"> </label>
<button onclick="button1Click()">button 1 </button>
<button onclick="button2Click()">button 2 </button>
```